# Define which type is inserted String or int

Tags: javascript

How to define which type of variable is typed in text field? I wish to type something inside text field when you press on **Search** button depending on type it should show you different results from database!

```
if(numbers 0-9){
   //do something
}  
else if (letters A-Z){
   //do something else
}
```

How to do that in javascript?

Comment: [Regular expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: What if there are numbers *and* letters? (Even if you don't *want* to allow this, prepare for it; because it *will* happen, even if only by accident.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most go with

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert a string into integer by doing:

```
var a = "3";
var b = +a; // this will try to convert a variable into integer if it can't it will be NaN
```

you can check if

```
Boolean(+a) is true then a is Number else it's not a number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the method `toType` defined by Angus Croll in this [blog post](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/):

```
var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}
```

Implementation:

```
toType({a: 4}); //"object"
toType([1, 2, 3]); //"array"
(function() {console.log(toType(arguments))})(); //arguments
toType(new ReferenceError); //"error"
toType(new Date); //"date"
toType(/a-z/); //"regexp"
toType(Math); //"math"
toType(JSON); //"json"
toType(new Number(4)); //"number"
toType(new String("abc")); //"string"
toType(new Boolean(true)); //"boolean"
```